# Getting weird characters through stdout when using a linked list with another struct as data

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, stdout

I wrote a program to save elements of the periodic table inputed through stdin into a linked list, and then print out the list. Each element is saved in a struct containing its information.

When I try to compile the program directly with gcc or clang, the list is not fully printed and I get a "zsh: segmentation fault". But when I use an online editor and compiler such as https://replit.com the code works without a problem. I'll leave the entire code below for reference. Hope someone can help with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element{
    char name[15];
    char symbol[2];
    double weight;
} element_t;

typedef struct node {
    element_t data;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

node_t *create_element_node(void)
{
    node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(element_t));
    printf("Element input: ");
    scanf("%s %s %lf", node->data.name, node->data.symbol, &(node->data.weight));
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void add_node_front(node_t **head, node_t *node_to_add)
{
    node_to_add->next = *head;
    *head = node_to_add;
    return;
}

void print_list(node_t *head)
{
    node_t *tmp = head;
    while(tmp != NULL){
        printf("%-15s%-7s%-2.4lf\n", tmp->data.name, tmp->data.symbol, tmp->data.weight);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    node_t *head = NULL, *tmp;

    //Populate the list with elements
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        tmp = create_element_node();
        add_node_front(&head, tmp);
    }

    printf("\n%-15s%-7s%-14s\n", "Element", "Symbol", "Atomic Weight");
    printf("%-15s%-7s%-14s\n", "___________", "______", "_____________");
    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(element_t))` -> `node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(node_t))` or better still `malloc(sizeof(*node))`

Comment: Element symbols are usually 2 characters long; you need one more byte allocated to store the null byte at the end.  Until a couple of years ago, there were some three-letter surrogate symbols for elements that had not yet been discovered (created) and named.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks a lot! This solved my problem. I didn't think it well through when making the allocation

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, I didn't account for that. Thanks!